# Python- how to get top terms per cluster after using EM clustering with doc2vec input file?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, doc2vec, expectation-maximization

I have collection of 300 docs.
I used doc2vec as input file for EM clustering. vector size = 30
I used WEKA to do the clustering. The result is in arff file.

sample:

```
id,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8.....,v30,cluster

1,2,1.663037,-1.773337,-8.800881,1.97047,-0.780625,4.85496,-3.119555,1.741365,-2.2641,-2.748193,1.39931,-0.174281,-4.877526,-0.40956,9.486185,3.560057,-1.522864,2.737845,2.681551,5.065698,4.56268,-4.083866,2.201541,-0.238072,-2.4043,1.099682,1.626528,1.093984,2.694377,-2.866608,cluster2

2,3,-3.772286,-5.115312,-11.506609,1.920562,-0.989224,-4.508823,1.921191,2.002067,-0.593291,2.785795,5.848867,0.081726,-6.277032,0.37599,11.993948,11.18893,-2.237655,-1.269672,6.688845,6.66756,9.476783,-2.536132,-1.408344,2.012941,4.015103,-5.578879,9.856035,-3.341312,5.27576,-1.708805,cluster3
```

Now, from these results, how can I get top 10 terms in each cluster ?

Comment: We'll need to see a code snippet to answer this properly

Answer (score 0):

There's no clear, common, 'correct' way of reporting what you've vaguely requested. (What, exactly, would "top 10 terms" mean?) But, here are some possibly useful steps that'd provide some plausibly-valuable terms reflective of each cluster.

`Doc2Vec` itself has no idea of clusters. For a single doc-vector, its model could be cajoled into ranking the most-predicted words, but that's not a usual operation. You could presumably repeat that over all the doc-vectors of all the docs in a cluster, and somehow combine the per-doc results to get a top-10 words over all docs. But that might not give a unique 10 words per cluster.

The clustering itself, since it's operating on just the dense doc-vectors, has no idea of words, so won't directly suggest relevant words.

Some modes of training `Doc2Vec` using the Gensim Python library will also train word-vectors at the same time, and into the same coordinate-space as the document vectors. Those modes are the default PV-DM mode (`dm=1`), or the PV-DBOW mode if you add the optional extra word-training (`dm=0, dbow_words=1`). In such a model, the word-vectors closest to a doc-vector may be especially descriptive of the doc-vector. So, you could consider compiling the top-N closest words to each of the M doc-vectors in a cluster, then taking the top-N words that appear highest in the most per-document top-N lists as being most related to the cluster.

You could also potentially just take the clusters as a given, ignoring completely the `Doc2Vec` modeling that helped create them, then use a more foundational technique like TFIDF term-weighting to pick some most-representative terms for each cluster.

For example, for every term in every document, calculate its TF/IDF value. Then, try different ways of tallying those values, per cluster. (Maybe, for term T, average the TFIDF of T in all in-cluster docs. Or add all the TFIDFs for term T. Or, synthesize a single combined document for each cluster including all that cluster's documents' words, and calculate TFIDF for each term in that pseudo-document.) Then, see which terms have the highest values in each cluster. That might give a top-10-terms ranking in the rough sense you're seeking.